# Как правильно подключать js код при помощи require

Tags: javascript

Из-за недостаточного опыта я не могу в полной мере описать вопрос, но надеюсь, что Вы поймете.
В file.js я подключаю другой файл

```
var test = require('./test.js');

var test1 = new test.Test1();
var test2 = new test.Test2();
```

А в test.js пишу типа

```
module.exports = {
    Test1: Test1,
    Test2: Test2
};

var Test1 = function(){

};

var Test2 = function(){

};
```

Но я не совсем уверен, что так делать правильно... Можно так делать или я смысл не понимаю?

**Дополнение:**

```
// у меня в коде написано вот так 
modele.exports = {
    Test: Test
};

var Test = function(){
    // ...
};

// но Вы делаете вот так - 
module.exports = {
    Test: Test
};

function Test(){
    //...
};

// и при этом делаете акцент на этом различии,
// говоря, что нужно делать, как у Вас.
// 
// И я спрашиваю, а в чем различия между 
// var Test и function Test ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

может `new test()` ?

Comment: Не видел ответа... Спасибо! Я не понимаю, что Вы хотели сказать.. Можно немного подробней?

Comment: ну у вас же судя по конструкции - модуль nodejs, зачем вам объекты всех его методов, если можно создать просто инстанс модуля (по аналогии `var fs=new Fs();`)

Comment: вот в таком виде:

app.js: 

    var test = require('./test.js');
    var test = new test();
    console.log(test.Test1());

test.js:

    module.exports = Test;

    function Test() {

    }


    Test.prototype.Test1=function(){
        return {t: this,r: Math.random()};
    };

    Test.prototype.Test2=function(){

    };

Comment: если же не надо объект инициализировать, то можно просто сделать (вот там у вас ошибка - Test1 - undefined был):

app.js:

    var test=require('./test.js');
    console.log(test.Test1());

test.js

    module.exports = {
        Test1: Test1,
        Test2: Test2
    };

    function Test1() {  //обратите внимание, не var Test1= а function Test1
       return {t: this,r: Math.random()};
    }

    function Test2() {

    }

Comment: @eicto, странно, что я не получал уведомлений о комментариях, Спасибо!  
Да, Вы правы, у меня nodejs и как Вы уже ответили, что лучше будет создавать инстенсы модулей.Но у меня вопрос по последниму комментарию - в чем разница, между присвоить ссылку на свойство, которое ссылается на анонимный метод и ссылкой на метод?

Comment: @vas не понял вашу терминологию. покажите мне чистый пример первого и второго.

Comment: Дописал в вопросе.